# Luks contents not visible/accessible - Manjaro Linux

Tags: manjaro, luks

just encrypted with Luks an USB pen drive using KDE partition manager on Manjaro. The operation went well and could mount the USB drive by entering the passphrase. As all permissions were set as root, I changed the ownership with my actual username so that I could copy all my contents from the SSD to the USB pen drive. Once restarted my machine, I was not able to see/access to my USB contents anymore (?!). The mount runs well but can't see nothing but just the folder name which initially contained all my stuff. The fact is that i can see the space which has been occupied (about 350MB) on the USB pen drive by my documents but is like nothing is there.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how KDE manage LUKS partitions.
If you want to do this manualy:

`lsblk` to geht your drive number /dev/xxx.

`sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/xxx usb` replace xxx with your device location.

With mount you can now mount the usb to your wish location `sudo mount /dev/mapper/usb /my_location` replace `my_location` with your mounting point. Now your mounting the mapper which cryptsetup created on your system.

To unmount the device: `sudo umount /dev/xxx` or `sudo unmount /my_location`.

You can see with `df -h` all your mounted devices.

Comment: Procedure above works well (works also using Dolphin file manager). Device is rightly mapped and mounted but still no sign of any contents. However, dissimilarities between KDE partition manager and df -h command concerning used space: KDE reports 345MB Vs 41MB reported from df -h